# the new facebook like, that open the comment box...+ overlow:hidden

Tags: css, facebook-like

a quick introduction :

facebook has changed the LIKE (count) button

into something like :

LIKE (count)

[ --------------------         clic =  open a Big zone bottom / right        --------------------]

problem :

Its nice BUT .... 
you forgot that a lot of website are using the like button in "toolbars". Page example

---

Header

Left column Tooblbar, include  fb:like   --------------------       Right column

Document content

Footer

---

and lot of structured pages/ blocs are using **"overflow:hidden"** !! So it makes the displayed widget randomly truncated everywhere (right, bottom...) depending of its environnement.

Its impossible to remove all the overflow:hidden from the containers blocks, to satisfy a widget update.

What can we do. Some sites where clean, now they look drafts, with all button opening truncated stuff...

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Facebook plugin, the only solution seems to be to change the HTML/CSS so overflow:hidden can be removed. Alternatively, you could try to use a service that forwards the user actions to social networks for you and offers different methods of website integration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `overflow: hidden` for semantic reasons, you could always change it to `overflow: visible` or just remove it. I'm assuming that the fix isn't that simple...

A quickfix that wouldn't require you to modify your CSS would be to place your FB Like button outside of any containing elements that have `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` and use absolute positioning to get it where you want it.